# Execution failed for task ':packageDebug' - ionic framework

Tags: android, ionic-framework

It was working properly.. But suddenly when I tried to run `ionic build android`, I got this error. I am not able to find out the issue.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':packageDebug'.
> Failed to add C:\git\personal\amarEla-app\platforms\android\build\intermediate
s\exploded-aar\android\CordovaLib\unspecified\debug\classes.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.603 secs

c:\git\personal\amarEla-app\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "c:\git\personal\amarEla-app\plat
forms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b c:\git\personal\amarEla-app\platforms\and
roid\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true"
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 8

You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (c:\Users\amitsinha02\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modu
les\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:134:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: remove platform android and then again try to build after adding platform.

Comment: @mudasserajaz... no.. getting the same error

Comment: Now getting `Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.`

Comment: that could be because of one of plugins. try removing pluigns one by one and see which made difference. or try updating cordova(if not updated already).

Comment: Found the issue.  It works fine after removing `com.google.playservices`.